# Google App Engine HTTP Error 403

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to write a simple Google App Engine application. I am following this tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/creating, however I cannot make it working.

When testing on the localhost, I receive:

```
HTTP ERROR 403
Problem accessing /. Reason:
    FORBIDDEN
Powered by Jetty://
```

This is my application code:

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class Test extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println("Hello, world");
    }
}
```

My web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Oracle Corporation//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>test.Test</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

My appengine-web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>halocline-test</application>
  <version>10</version>

  <!--
    Allows App Engine to send multiple requests to one instance in parallel:
  -->
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

  <!-- Configure java.util.logging -->
  <system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
  </system-properties>

  <!--
    HTTP Sessions are disabled by default. To enable HTTP sessions specify:

      <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>

    It's possible to reduce request latency by configuring your application to
    asynchronously write HTTP session data to the datastore:

      <async-session-persistence enabled="true" />

    With this feature enabled, there is a very small chance your app will see
    stale session data. For details, see
    http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Enabling_Sessions
  -->

</appengine-web-app>
```

Console output:

```
Jul 06, 2012 2:42:34 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
Jul 06, 2012 2:42:35 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\Halocline\workspace\Test\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Jul 06, 2012 2:42:35 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\Halocline\workspace\Test\war\WEB-INF/web.xml
Jul 06, 2012 3:42:36 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The server is running at http://localhost:8888/
Jul 06, 2012 3:42:36 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin
```

No errors are shown in the console when I open localhost:8888 in my web browser.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You servlet is mapped to `http://localhost:8888/test`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works. However when I deploy this application and access MyAppID.appspot.com/test I get the following error:

Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.

If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.

Comment: Look at the log files on appengine.

Comment: @Jaroslaw Pawlak: See the log files in the admin console

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might have your index.html file in a wrong directory. Check it did not accidentally slip under `WEB-INF`. It should be directly under `war`.