# Google App Engine NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR Eclipse build error

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin

I have installed Google App Engine plugin for Eclipse Indigo. I have created new Web Application Project with auto generated sample code. I unchecked "use Google Web Toolkit" when creating a project. My project looks as described here: [Google App Engine HTTP Error 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365100/google-app-engine-http-error-403)

When building the project, I get the following error:

> Errors occurred during the build.
>
> Errors running builder 'Google App Engine Project Change Notifier' on project 'Test
>
> NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: An attempt is made to modify an object where modifications are not allowed.

I can run the servlet on the localhost, without any problems, however when I deploy the application, it doesn't work. Logs show:

> Uncaught exception from servlet
>
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: test/Test : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by Java 7. Google App Engine supports Java 6 only.

Comment: I am definitely using java 6 but am still having the same problem. I went as far as removing my eclipse juno installation and reinstalled everything again. This started happening when I upgraded to GAE 1.7.1. It stops when I disable Google App Engine Project Change Notifier in the eclipse builders but not sure if this builder is necessary.

Comment: This is an answer...but how to fix it would have been nice.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be related to [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-plugin-for-eclipse/issues/detail?id=90) the suggested workaround from the thread worked for me (pasted here for convenience):

> As a temporary workaround, navigate to Project Properties -> Builders and disable the "Google App Engine Change Notifier" builder.